# Stack Photos Throwing effect Using jquery

Tags: jquery

I want implement stack photos image gallery like photo is thrown by hand.

like this: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FlohNb8rnR8

I tried using jquery animate and drop effect but it doesn't look similar. Any idea how can i implement?

Thanks.

Comment: Please post some code showing what you've tried.

Answer (score 1):

I highly recommend using [greensock](http://www.greensock.com/v12/) for animation over jquery's animate. Greensock has a lot of nice easing options to get nice smooth motion with controllable easing.

Check out the [speed test](http://www.greensock.com/js/speed.html) comparing different JS engines.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to have all the images absolutely positioned and off the screen, then one at a time animate their position somewhere randomly onto the screen, each one having a higher z-index than the previous one.

With jQuery's callback functions you can smoothly get each one to come up after the other.
You'll need to come up with some math.random logic with limitations (probably on window height/width etc). But basically the idea is somewhat like this.

```
var zindex = 100;

$('img').each(function () {
    $(this).css('z-index', zindex++)
           .animate({ top: _yVariable, left: _xVariable }, _timeVariable, function () {
       return; //restart loop once this animations finished
    });     
});
```